# Windows CMD.exe inserting new line after program runs

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd

Does CMD.exe automatically put a new line on the terminal window after a program has run?
My program is outputing one line of text via .NET. Here is the code: `Console.WriteLine("TEXT");`
However, I'm also seeing a blank line when I run it in CMD.exe.
Why is that?

It would look like this:

```
TEXT

C:\>
```

Notice the blank line in the above output. My program only writes 1 line though.

Comment: It doesn't insert a new line after a program runs, but it does insert a new line before it presents the prompt, which has the same effect in this context.  This is for aesthetic reasons.  Without the blank line before the prompt, it would be harder to see where the output from the program ends.

Comment: _Console.Write("TEXT");_ and look for the difference

Comment: The thing that I need to validate is that _my_ program is only producing _1_ line of text. If Windows does, it's okay.

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you can provide a reference for your comment, you should write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: No reference needed; you can confirm this behaviour yourself using built-in commands like `echo`.  But to validate your program unambiguously, redirect the output to a file, i.e., `myprogram > test.txt`.  You'll find that the file contains only the one line.

Comment: @HarryJohnston have you tested your statement about redirecting? I have redirected my program's standard output to a file `output.txt` And opening it with `notepad` still shows one blank line.

Comment: Just wondering, what's the point of multi-posting the same question on several SE sites, under different user names, without at least cross-referencing the posts? I am referring to [Windows CMD.exe inserting new line after program runs](http://superuser.com/questions/1033282/windows-cmd-exe-inserting-new-line-after-program-runs).

Comment: Works fine for me.  (Of course notepad, like most text editors, allows you to put the cursor at the beginning of where the next line would go.  Perhaps you're misinterpreting that as "a blank line"?)  If you want to be absolutely certain, write a program that opens the file (in binary mode) and prints out the hexadecimal value of the characters one by one.

Answer (score -1):

The method `WriteLine()` adds a new line to its output text.
If you would use `Write()` method like @Steve suggested you would not see a new line.

Hope that helps.